# Frequency response of the wireless channel

Tags: fourier-transform, radio, radio-frequency

We know that the signal attenuates out with distance and according to the channel transfer function or frequency response, the signal frequency components attenuate to different values based on frequency.

The effect of distance is widely acknowledged & used in practice as a path-loss model which is exponentially decreasing in distance but frequency component is relatively less discussed.

It is very embarrassing to find that the everyday used wireless channel's transfer function is not known to most of us!

I searched all over the web with all naive keywords but it seems the spectrum of the channel transfer function is not there anywhere not even in many text books!

On the similar lines, what is the typical conclusion about the spectrum? are high frequencies better for something that we always modulate to higher frequencies or it is just that we have available bands there?

Comment: Path loss models are frequency dependent too.  There really is no such thing as a free-space channel transfer function.  There are models that use Rayleigh Fading/Doppler/delays/shifts/interference to simulate free space propagation.

Comment: Common path loss models: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/83151/radio-transmission-distance-fm/83156#83156