# Is there a quantifiable tradeoff (in terms of effective broadcast distance) between the height of a radio tower and the power of the transmitter?

Tags: radio

I have a dataset on radio stations with the following variables:

- the power of the transmitter, in watts
- the coordinates of the radio tower

I can easily get the elevation at those coordinates and the average elevation of the surrounding area. I know that estimating the broadcast range or the radio horizon of a transmitter is a [complicated question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10139/83985), and I know there are [simple estimates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-of-sight_propagation#Radio_horizon) like this:

\begin{equation}
\text{horizon}_{\text{km}} \approx 3.57 \sqrt{\text{height}_{\text{metres}}}
\end{equation}

Are there similarly simple estimates for how this horizon changes with the power of the transmitter, assuming the same frequency, elevation, and tower height?

For example, if there are two towers of the same height at the same coordinates (yes, I know this is impossible), but one has a 1 kW transmitter and the other has a 50 kW transmitter, is there a way to adjust the equation above to account for this difference in power? **Am I wrong to assume that the more powerful transmitter will have a larger range, all else being equal?**

Comment: The short paper linked below gives an overview of this subject including the relationship of the received surface waves of AM broadcast stations to their operating frequencies, applied powers, path lengths, and the characteristics of the Earth along which those waves propagate. I am the author of this paper. http://rfry.org/Software%20Download/Freq%20and%20Conductivity%20as%20Factors%20in%20MW%20Field%20Intensity.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The power of the transmitter is completely independent of the height of the tower: it depends only on some design features of the antenna: the actual shape, the input current, the impedence etc.  Based on geometrical arguments, the power roughly drops like $1/r^2$ (at least in the far field).

The angular *distribution* of this power does depend on antenna characteristics, i.e. a half-wave dipole does not radiate in the same way as a Hertzian dipole.  This will depend on the relative geometry of the antenna and the reception point, v.g. there might be particular orientations where the antenna doesn't radiate for instance.

As specific example, the radiation pattern of a [short (or Hertizian) dipole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_antenna#Dipole_variations) looks like

[image]

i.e. the short dipole does not radiate in the line of the antenna.  Intuitively, this can be understood as there is no magnetic field in the line along a finite current-carrying wire that generates the magnetic field.

For the full-wavelength dipole we have a more flatten pattern

[image]

and, for some specific antenna arrays, one can obtain very directional signals, as shown below:

[image]

As a result, concentration of the signal (as measured by the [directivity of the antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directivity)), is highly dependent on the type of antenna.  Clearly the directivity will affect the range, and the reception of the signal will depend on the relative orientation of the receiver w/r to the antenna.

Comment: Hmmm, ok. I know the power is completely independent of the height of the tower, but that doesn't mean that the power doesn't affect the range of the station, right?

Comment: This will depend on the sensitivity of your receiver but for fixed sensitivity the power density will drop like $1/r^2$ so to double the range you need to quadruple the power.

Comment: Since I don't have any data on the height of the tower (these are historical data from the 1920s), I was hoping to use the strength/wattage of the transmitter as another proxy or extremely coarse estimate of the approximate range.

Comment: @MichaelA added some additional material to my original answer.

Comment: This is really helpful. I think my first step is to just hold everything else constant, so to speak, and use the inverse-square law you mentioned as a really rough estimate. I know that's far from perfect, but I think it's all I can do with the data I have.

Answer (score 1):

for AM radio signals, the tower height is almost always related to the wavelength of the transmission, according to the specifics of the antenna design (quarter-wave, half-wave, or 5/8ths wave base-fed vertical, etc.). the transmitted power is set by the range limits of the station's operating license, to prevent interference with other stations operating on the same frequency in the region. both ground-wave propagation and ionospheric reflection are significant for this type of transmission, so over-the-horizon signals are common and line-of-sight rules do not apply.

for FM and TV signals, neither ground-wave nor ionospheric skip effects are significant, but line-of-sight is. this means tower height is all-important and establishes the maximum range. the station operator then chooses a big enough transmitter to cover that area with a strong signal, which can be in the range of ~millions of watts for a TV signal.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm only interested in AM signals at the moment because I'm looking at historical radio stations (like in the early 1920s). It's just that I don't have *any* data on the height of the tower, so I was hoping to use the wattage of the transmitter as another proxy or *very* rough estimate for the range.

Comment: why not give this a shot on the amateur radio stack exchange? there are a lot of old-timers over there who might have info of use to you. -NN

Comment: I think I should maybe ask another question for this, but can you give me an example of how, in the most *basic* sense, I would apply an inverse-square law to a radio wave's propagation? I know that ground wave propagation is significant for certain frequencies, but I mean as in "500 W (i.e. 57 dBm) transmitter at some point on flat ground, what is the signal strength in dBm 10 km away?" I'm having trouble figuring this out.

Comment: if we imagine a source sitting on the ground, and free space around it, then doubling the distance cuts the strength to 1/4 and yes, there is a dB-based formula for this which you can get off the amateur radio stack exchange- that's where I take questions like this. lots of helpful people over there.